# How to import png icons to JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, import

I stumble upon a problem when I was trying to import icons to JS file, it doesn't work, I did some research online but nothing helped me, is it possible to import pngs to a vanilla js file, or maybe is possible to import whole png folder? How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="x"></div>

<script>
    let img = document.createElement("img");

    img.src = "sample.png"

    let src = document.getElementById("x");

    src.appendChild(img);
</script>
```

Try this code...

Comment: I don't want to create an element, I want to import it to JS file, actually, I figured out how to import single png e.g:  import drop from 'url:../images/weather-icons/drop.png', url: at the beginning was crucial, but here comes a question how to import a folder or if it is possible because I need multiple images. I'm using parcel for build proccess.

Comment: Currently I don't know any way of importing folder. I will surely look into it. Let me know if you find any.